# Vue - Access prop in child component, regular javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am loading a Vue component from another Vue component and am passing a property to that component. I need to access this property in the regular javascript of that component, but cannot figure out how to do this.

The simplified parent component could look as follows:

```
<template>
  <div>
     <MenuEdit :menu-list="menuList"></MenuEdit>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MenuEdit from '@/components/MenuEdit';

export default {
  name: 'Admin',
  data: function () {
    return {
      menuList: ["Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4"]
    };
  },
  components: {
    MenuEdit
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

And the MenuEdit could look as follows:

```
<template>
  <div>
      {{ menuList }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
//console.log(this.menuList) // Does not work.

export default {
  name: 'MenuEdit',
  props: [
      'menuList'
  ],
  methods: {
    testMenu: function() {
      console.log(this.menuList) //This works fine
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

EDIT

To add some context to the question, I am implementing sortablejs on Buefy using the following example: https://buefy.org/extensions/sortablejs

Instead of calling "vnode.context.$buefy.toast.open(`Moved ${item} from row ${evt.oldIndex + 1} to ${evt.newIndex + 1}`)" at the end of the first const, I want to update the component (or better said, update the related Array).

In the example, the const are defined outside of the component, which is why I ended up with this question.

Comment: Your component logic is inside the curly brackets of `export default{...}` outside that you could not access the component properties

Comment: Just to clarify: you're using a single-file component here, right?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: if you do it like this you probably doing something wrong

Comment: I added some context to the question including the official documentation that I am using. But it's well possible that I am doing something wrong, I just don't know what...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the prop as that code (where your console.log is) runs before the component is mounted, before it's even declared really

If you want to access stuff when the component is first mounted, you can use the [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) lifecycle method